# Instance member 'task' can't be accessed using static access

Tags: flutter, dart

I cannot figure out the problem. Please can you help.
I have tried everything I can find, I am still relatively new to coding and still learning dart.
Here is the code:

```
class Task {

  String task;

  Task(this.task);

}

class TaskCard extends StatelessWidget {

  final Task task;
  final Function() done;
  TaskCard({required this.task, required this.done});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 16.0, 16.0, 0.0),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(
              Task.task, // here is the error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REplace with this:

```
Text(
      task.task
```

Answer (score 0):

before task declaration write `static` keyword.

```
static String task;
```